# Troubleshooting HDMI connection between MBP and Sony Bravia TV

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, hdmi, displayport

I'm trying to connect my MacBook Pro (late 2011) running Mavericks to my Sony Bravia television like so: MBP thunderbolt port -> Mini DisplayPort cable -> HDMI cable -> TV HDMI 1 port.

However, I'm not getting any picture or sound on the television. Neither device has recognised the other.

Have I missed something out?

Comment: has the hardware worked (the cables) anywhere else to confirm.

Comment: you have one to many, it should be MBP thunderbolt to HDMI cable adopter-- HDMI cable to TV (no mini DisplayPort cable

Comment: Apologies - it's a mini DisplayPort to HDMI adaptor. I'm afraid I don't have any other way of testing the hardware.

Comment: do you have xbox. or anything else with hmdi on it

Comment: Having the same issue. Using an Apple Macbook pro 2011 with a sony Bravia tv.
The Tv received signal till about 2 weeks ago, till it suddenly just died.
I thought the cable was busted, so i changed the HDMI cable as well as the Minidisplay to HDMI, but still no luck. I tried connecting my Macbook Air and have the same issue on the same TV as well as another sony bravia. Don't know if its a os issue, as the same worked a couple of weeks ago and now does not. Also i tried using a VGA cable to connect the macbook air & pro and that seems to work. I have even tried to reset the SMC & PRAM reset as

Answer (score 1):

This problem could also be caused by a missing or improper [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) signal coming from the MiniDisplayport-to-HDMI adapter.

I experienced the same issue with my MacbookPro (late 2008) and a Bravia TV. I tried one cable with a MiniDisplayport connector on one end and HDMI plug at the other. This worked fine between my MBP and a computer monitor or a beamer, but would not transmit any signal to a Sony Bravia TV. An adapter (of the cheaper kind) displayed the same behavior. The used HDMI cable was fine (tested between PS3 and the TV). Again, adapter and cable produced a proper signal on non-Bravia displays. A Dr. Bott MiniDisplayport-to-HDMI adapter finally solved the matter for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the assumption you cables re fine...

find other devices with HDMI input (game consoles ect..) to cross check.

Try this..

> SMC RESET
>
> ```
> Shut down the computer.
> Unplug the computer's power cord and all peripherals.
> Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> Release the power button.
> Attach the computers power cable.
> Press the power button to turn on the computer.
> ```
>
> PRAM RESET
>
> ```
> Shut down the computer.
> Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command, Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.
> Turn on the computer.
> Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys. You must press this key combination before the gray screen appears.
> Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
> Release the keys.
> ```

The Sony should show up in your display profiles even if the TV is OFF.

[Try to reset your Sony.](http://community.sony.com/t5/Television-Picture-Sound/HDMI-ports-not-working-on-kdl-40xbr4/td-p/27387).

> 1. Turn off the TV and unplug all the HDMI connections to the TV.
> 2. Turn on the TV and while holding down the up arrow on the remote control, press the power button on the TV.
> 3. The TV will turn itself off, then back on again then release the up arrow button.
> 4. Complete the initial TV setup wizard.
> 5. Turn off the TV and plug back all the HDMI connections to the TV.
> 6. Turn on the TV and verify those connected HDMI inputs are working or not.

Also look up what Profiles you have in the `/System/Library/CoreServices/Resources`

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere it is losing quality and power etc. Try getting a direct HDMI converter. Buy the original Apple Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter and try again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with the help of telephone support. Initially I was disheartened after reading all that has been written in this particular article comments section, but luckily I managed to crack this.

I had earlier used a samsung with the mac mini, and straight out of the box, it matched with the samsung. It appears that this leaves the mac mini with the memory of the samsung. Hence when connecting with HDMI to a Sony Bravia, the mac mini did not recognise the Sony and vice versa.

I switched off the mac mini, disconnected the HDMI, connected it back, switched on the mac mini, AND HELD DOWN THE OPTION BUTTON THROUGHOUT, then pressed CMD+F1. That did the trick partially. Then i restarted the mac mini, as before. Everything now sings.

I also have a USB out to my DAC for music, which is the principal purpose of the mac mini. That has stayed undisturbed. But in the quicktime / ELMedia player etc. to play the movies in different formats, it is necessary to switch the output from built in speakers to an amplifier (painfully, every time) and then the sound comes from the amp-speaker combo and the picture from the TV.

The less elegant way to do all this is to have a Apple TV connected by ethernet or wifi to your router, and a mac mini to the same router, and then the Sony TV will accept anything your mac mini has, provided it is iTunes compatible.

If the apple TV is jailbriken, then you can use some other formats and a whole lot of other programs. There is plenty of literature around the how and why of apple Tv jailbreaking.

Hope this helps everyone.

Comment: do you mean to say you have solved your problem on your equipment, not the the problem of the original poster. ?

Answer (score -1):

It is a known fact that Mac to Samsung monitors or TVs do not work.  I spent $500 on dual Samsung monitors and it didn't work correctly.

Comment: This seems like an overly broad statement. Also - directly connecting an issue with a specific samsung product seems tenuous if someone has a sony issue.

Comment: i used a samsung monitor  on my mac for years.