# Connecting Macbook Air to Sony HDTV via HDMI

Tags: macos, hdmi

I own an apple Macbook Air early 2015 version, I am not able to connect it to my Sony HDTV through mini DP to HDMI converter. Can somebody Help?

Comment: Can you add more info please? What's not working? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks JMY, I have tried the same connection process with my other HDTV of Panasonic make, there it works. When I connect it to the Sony TV the screen simply remains blank showing a no signal message. However on checking the HDMI menu on the TV a connection is detected but there is no signal. Is there a different configuration of HDMI on Sony TV?

Answer (score -1):

The Macbook Air (2015) edition has a thunderbolt output. You'll need a adapter from Thunderbolt to HDMI to get this working.

Also:

1. did you checked the HDMI cable if this one is working
2. Is the channel set properly on your Sony TV?

Comment: Thanks rwzdoorn, but my MBA connects to another panasonic TV using the same connector & HDMI Cable. Does Sony HDMI connector have a different configuration than the stock HDMI?

Comment: Did you checked [this topic?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131049/troubleshooting-hdmi-connection-between-mbp-and-sony-bravia-tv)  Same problem with minidisplayport to HDMI with Sony Bravia TV.